# Gradient with python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a little problem with the function gradient (numpy).

I have two lists: `T` concerning times, `F` concerning position. I just want to calculate DF with `numpy.gradient`. Is it okay if I do `numpy.gradient(T,F)`?

It seems to be easy, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)? It clearly shows that `numpy.gradient` doesn't work like that.

Comment: You probably need something like `numpy.diff(F)/numpy.diff(T)`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under the assumption that you're asking for df/d.? You have to covert your lists to np arrays, first.  So,

```
naF = np.array(F)
naT = np.array(T)
```

Then you would use:

```
np.gradient(naT,np.gradient(naF))
```

You need that gradient of F inside the gradient of T, otherwise, the step size is just the array values of F.